# The current environment does not support the specified persistence type

Tags: firebase-authentication, react-native

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

> The default for web browser and React Native apps is local (provided the browser supports this storage mechanism, eg. 3rd party cookies/data are enabled) whereas it is none for Node.js backend apps.

When I try the following in my React Native Android app:

```
const signIn = () =>
  firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => {
    return firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
  });
```

I get the following error:

```
The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.
```

Is this a bug or have I missed something from the docs?

Environment:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.4",
  }

Android 7.0
```

Comment: Hey Prashanth, this was released in 4.2.0: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.2.0 Can you try downgrading to that version to see if this a regression?

Comment: Downgrading to 4.2.0 did not solve the issue. Adding `firebase.default.INTERNAL.extendNamespace({
  INTERNAL: {
      reactNative: {
          AsyncStorage: AsyncStorage
      }
  }
});` right before setting persistence makes the error go away, though the auth is still not persisted between app relaunch (different user.uid each time).

Comment: I found the root cause. I was using selective imports i.e. `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'`. Switching to `import firebase from 'firebase'` solves the issue.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the update.

Comment: I have the same issue with v4.5.0 but I already imported this way. Any other solution? Logged user is not being persisted anymore after upgrading from 4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there's a bug in selectively importing firebase modules.
Changing the imports from

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

to

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

solved the issue.

Comment: I suggest following up by creating an issue in the firebase-js-sdk repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues. Let everyone else know what worked for you, or if you find a better solution.

Comment: @roiekoper I had this issue in 4.5.1 (already doing `import firebase from 'firebase'`) and upgrading to 4.6.0 fixed the issue for me